# QnA Maker Knowledge Base returning ‘No good match found in KB’ for follow-up prompts

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker

I’ve got an issue with my QnA Knowledge Base where it’s retuning ‘No good match found in KB’ when using follow-up prompts that I've configured to return an answer.

I have c.200 question/answer pairs set up and all of them have follow-up prompts linking each question/answer pair to other question/answer pairs. However, when I test the knowledge base in QnA Maker I get an answer of ‘No answer found in KB’.

Below is an example:

I have a question/answer pair to answer the question ‘What is depression’ that has five different follow-up prompts - Prevalence, Causes, Types, Symptoms and Related Issues:

[image: Image of ‘What is depression’ QnA question/answer pair]

As you can see in the below image, the Prevalence follow-up prompt is configured to answer using the ‘How common is depression’ questions/answer pair:

[image: Image of Prevalence follow-up prompt configuration]

However, when I test this using QnA Maker’s built in test chatbot I get the answer ‘No good match found in KB’:

[image: Image of Prevalence follow-up prompt answer in test chatbot]

When I inspect the result I see the following:

[image: Image of inspection of Prevalence follow-up prompt answer]

As you can see, there is no answer returned and the confidence score is 'None'.

Has anyone else seen this problem before and have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow-up prompts aren't currently supported out of the box outside of the QnA Maker portal. There is a [C#](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/experimental/qnamaker-prompting/csharp_dotnetcore) and [NodeJS](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/experimental/qnamaker-prompting/javascript_nodejs) experimental samples available which demonstrate how you can integrate this functionality into your bot.

Since you haven't specified a language preference, I will go with the C# one, basically your QnA code needs to be updated from something like:

```
var qnaMaker = new QnAMaker(new QnAMakerEndpoint
{
    KnowledgeBaseId = _configuration["QnAKnowledgebaseId"],
    EndpointKey = _configuration["QnAEndpointKey"],
    Host = _configuration["QnAEndpointHostName"]
},
null,
httpClient);

var response = await qnaMaker.GetAnswersAsync(turnContext);

if (response != null && response.Length > 0)
{
    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(response[0].Answer), cancellationToken);
}
else
{
    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("No QnA Maker answers were found."), cancellationToken);
}
```

to:

```
var qnaMaker = new QnAMaker(new QnAMakerEndpoint
{
    KnowledgeBaseId = _configuration["QnAKnowledgebaseId"],
    EndpointKey = _configuration["QnAEndpointKey"],
    Host = _configuration["QnAEndpointHostName"]
},
null,
httpClient);

var response = await qnaMaker.GetAnswersAsync(turnContext);
var qnaAnswer = response[0].Answer;
var prompts = response[0].Context?.Prompts;

if (prompts == null || prompts.Length < 1)
{
    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(response[0].Answer), cancellationToken);
}
else
{
    // Set bot state only if prompts are found in QnA result
    newState = new QnABotState
    {
        PreviousQnaId = response[0].Id,
        PreviousUserQuery = query
    };

    outputActivity = CardHelper.GetHeroCard(qnaAnswer, prompts);
}
```

The relevant code is in [this file](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/experimental/qnamaker-prompting/csharp_dotnetcore/Dialogs/QnADialog.cs#L26), as you can see there is some additional code involved to store the progress through the follow-up prompts, so perhaps it might be easier to plug in your KB details to the sample then try it out to see how it works before porting it over into your bot.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'll take a look - I'm using NodeJS for my bot but didn't think that would be relevant as I'm seeing these issues in the QnA Maker test chatbot and assumed it was an issue with the Knowledge Base. Is part of the problem that the QnA Maker test chatbot hasn't been updated to support follow-up prompts?

Comment: Oh right, you're getting the issue inside the QnA Maker portal itself, I totally misread your question. I will see if I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Yes, exactly that but for multiple topics such as depression, anxiety, phobias, OCD etc...

Comment: Would you mind using the export knowledgebase functionality then posting a link to it so that I can import it to see what is going on? It's doing my head in trying to add the follow-up prompts manually to all of the similar names at different levels. Alternatively there is the [collaborate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/collaborate-knowledge-base) option.

Comment: Yes, adding the prompts is time consuming! [Here's](https://mihndbotblob.blob.core.windows.net/resources/MiHNDbot_KB_10-07-19.tsv) the KB. Happy to add you to the KB as well if easier, will just need your email I think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196253/discussion-between-matt-stannett-and-sean).

Answer (score 0):

With Matt's help we did some testing of the portal chatbot vs. the QnA API and found that there is a bug with the portal chatbot as the API returns the answers as expected. I am following up by posting details of this as feedback on the BotFramework documentation page [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/quickstarts/create-publish-knowledge-base#test-the-knowledge-base)